# Why is my javascript function finding my checkbox to be false

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

My code looks something like this

**HTML**

```
<div><input type="checkbox" name="showInactiveBox" value="showInactiveBox" id="showInactiveBox">Show inactive project numbers</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#showInactiveBox").live("click", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) { //checkbox is checked
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("UpdateInactiveBox", "Project")",
            data: {
                showInactive: true
            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            Debug.writeln("Check box is checked?: " + $("#showInactiveBox").is(":checked"));

            $("#project-numbers-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        });
```

I have an else that looks similar to above, just sets the checkbox to false basically. My debug line above in the .done of the Ajax function returns the correct value whether it be checked or not. However I then call the .read() on my grid which relates to more javascript below:

```
read: {
                url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetActiveProjectNumbers", "Project"))",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: function () {
                        var model = {
                            projectid: "@Model.Id",
                        };
                        return JSON.stringify(model);
                    },
                    showinactive: $("#showInactiveBox").is(":checked")
                }
            },
```

When I put another Debug.writeline in the server, it is receiving the correct value for "q" but "showinactive" is always read in as false. Is there something with javascript that I don't quite understand where going from function to function will read a different value for ($"checkboxid").is(":checked")?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
 showinactive: $("#showInactiveBox").is(":checked")
```

to

```
 showinactive: function() {
    return $("#showInactiveBox").is(":checked");
 }
```

and call it with

```
showinactive()
```

Currently, you are setting `showinactive` to the value of the property, which I'm assuming starts as false. Values in javascript don't update with the DOM like that--you need to explicitly check each time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure .is() works with the jQuery version you are running? You could also try .prop('checked'). I would try running this in the Chrome developer tools on the page:

```
$("#showInactiveBox").is(":checked")
```

and

```
$("#showInactiveBox").prop("checked")
```

If those return the value you are looking for, then there is something else going on. Try running those in console.log at the point at which you are calling those functions to see what the active output is:

```
console.log('This is my checkbox value', $("#showInactiveBox").is(":checked"));
```

Comment: Changing it to .prop where I pass it to the server actually causes an error because - when I do it in my debug lines, it passes back as undefined.

Comment: Curious, were you able to try the console.log message to see what value is appearing at time of being called? Or even using the .is()? What I was curious about is if its sending the right value, but perhaps your server side controller is looking for the wrong data type.

Comment: Unfortunately there is something wrong (and very bizarre) with my user validation that when I try to run this locally on Chrome/firefox it will not correctly authenticate me and let me in to the application and so I'm forced to test in IE... However it works fine in production lol..

Comment: That's all that matters! :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lawrence Johnson's (`.prop`) answer I'd take a look at some of the other code you are using.

For instance, when dealing with checkboxes it's always better to use the `.change()` method rather than click.

Also, the .live method is deprecated now and should be using `.on()`.

When dealing with checkboxes you can easily use "vanilla javascript" to test if the box is checked or not. jQuery is not always the "less code/best solution".

See the below code for all the amendments mentioned above:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="showInactiveBox" value="showInactiveBox" id="showInactiveBox">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#showInactiveBox').on('change',function(){ //using .on and change rather than click

        if ( this.checked ) {//test if checked or not
            console.log('checked');
        }

    })  
});
</script>
```